# How do i delay execution of a sampler from thread group "X" until a sampler from thread group "Y" has finished in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Hello i have the following problem :I have a Thread group "X" which has a sampler that creates a document in a system. Thread group "Y" has a sampler which takes the document ID from thread group "X" - both actions must be performed by a different user one by one and than continue the execution of their other samplers that's why i have put them in a different thread groups (they are performing different visitor scenarios). If i use "Run thread groups consecutively" the second document ID is the only one which is passed to Thread group "Y". The best resolution for me would be if there is a way to tell thread group "Y" to sleep just before asking for the document for a time just after the document has being created in Thread group "X" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand from this question, You do not want to use `Run thread groups consecutively`. But somehow you want the threadgroup Y to wait for a sample to finish in threadgroup X.

---

If so, You can create a property in thread group X

`${__setProperty("docid", ${yourdocumentid})}`;

You can access it in thread group Y by using a whil econtroller.

Use a while controller in thread group Y to make the threadgroup Y until the docid is set to a number other than 0 by thread group X. This will be the while loop condition.

```
${__javaScript("${__P(docid,0)}" == "0")}
```

You might want to change it back to 0 immediately.

---

you can also use [Inter-Thread Communication](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin.

[image]

Comment: Thank you really much that's exactly what i needed really appreciate it !